# Copy a SQL Server database from one server to another on demand

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two servers, Prod and Test, both running SQL Server 2008 RTM.

Is it possible to have a PowerShell- or VBScript that could copy a database from one server to another?

The copy should of course include all contents of the database, with the exception of privileges so I don't lock myself out from editing the destination.

The destination database should be cleared/reset or completely overwritten, so both source and destination are identical.

Additionally, the connection to the source should be read-only and (if possible) only able to initiate the copy process without actually having access to the data.

I am slightly familiar with PowerShell, so if this only means connecting and starting a task it should be doable. Or do I have to look for advanced solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: why you don't do a sql JOB that backup and restore your database ?

Comment: How large is the database? If it's particularly big then backup/restore will be the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: @KiKine, I am not too familiar with MSSQL, hence my question. If it is possible to have a job that is remotely executed on demand, them I am all for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have two servers, Prod and Test, both running SQL Server 2008 RTM. Is it possible to have a PowerShell- or VBScript that could copy a database from one server to another?

You have couple of options :

1. Use [Ola's solution](http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) to do backup on PROD server and then schedule the script in SQL Agent job to **a.** do backup, **b.** copy the backupfile to test server and **c.** restore the backup on the test server.
2. use PowerShell to do the job.

   - [Use PowerShell To Copy A Database To Another Instance](http://www.kendalvandyke.com/2013/02/t-sql-tuesday-39-use-powershell-to-copy.html)
   - [backup and restore your databases using SQL Server PowerShell and SMO.](http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44909)
   - [Backup and Restore SQL Server with the SQL Server 2012 PowerShell cmdlets](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/backup-and-recovery/backup-and-restore-sql-server-with-the-sql-server-2012-powershell-cmdlets/)

> The copy should of course include all contents of the database, with the exception of privileges so I don't lock myself out from editing the destination.

The database backup includes all the data in the database when the FULL backup was taken including the database users. When you restore the database on Test server, make sure to SYNC Orphan users.

> The destination database should be cleared/reset or completely overwritten, so both source and destination are identical.

When you restore the database, you have to use [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) option to overwrite the files with the new ones.

> I am slightly familiar with PowerShell, so if this only means connecting and starting a task it should be doable. Or do I have to look for advanced solutions?

You can schedule the script to run at specific time or just run it on demand. Refer to the links that I have suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is that this is possible but not straight forward and doing so in read only mode and w/o being able to read data is going to be challenging.

If source database is running then you just can’t copy it because SQL Server will prevent you to do so. This means that you’ll either have to stop SQL Server service or connect to SQL Server to create a backup. In either case you’ll need a level of privileges that can probably access the data.

What I would do is:

- Create VB Script to backup database
- Create bat script to zip–copy–unzip database backup
- Create another VB Script on destination server to restore database backup

Comment: You'll also need to sort out the permissions, if the requirements are different between prod & dev.  But that's straightforward, assuming you have the appropriate rights on the dev server.

Comment: `This means that you’ll either have to stop SQL Server service or connect to SQL Server to create a backup.` is totally incorrect point. why would you stop sql server service to take a backup ?

Answer (score 0):

As to the person kicking off the job not having access to the data, there's a stored procedure--sp_start_job--in 2005 and higher.  The person kicking off the job would only need the one of the SQL Agent roles granted to them, such as SQLAgentOperatorRole.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We created a SQL job to do that. Basically it has 4 steps:

1. Backup the database to a shared network folder
2. Drop the test database
3. Restore the backup taken in step 1 as the test database
4. Delete the backup

On nights that we want to do the copy we just tick the box in SQL Server Agent Scheduler and go home. Come in the next morning and it's all done.

We normally do it at night because that's when the server is at its quietest. There is no reason that you can't do it during normal operations - none of the steps requires taking the live database offline. But we found that the CPU time and network traffic made it more favourable to do it out of business hours.